# Getting Null for boolean type after json.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, string, object, parsing

I have to copy an object in javascript and for doing that i am using JSON.stringfy() but when i again convert that copied object to object form , it is showing null value for boolean type rather than showing the initial vaue

eg:

```
let objCopy = json.stringfy(obj);  
// it converts the whole obj into a string form and stores it in objCopy

// now after performing some actions , i again want to restore the original value 
obj = json.parse(objCopy);
```

Now one of the fields in the "obj" is that of boolean type and when I use parse() method the value which is storing in that boolean variable is null (rather than true or false)

Comment: Add an example on the initial `obj` value. I tested on simple object and the boolean value is parsed back correctly. Looking into your real `obj` value may help.

Comment: There's a typo here for stringify, is it correct for the original code ?

Comment: @AmeyaR yes it is correct for original code

Comment: @Yoel were you able to get my question , i am trying the restore the original value of my object but when i parse the copied value of the object , one of the fields in the object is of boolean type and it is getting to null while its original value was "true"

Comment: I don't have any problem when trying to parse a simple object with boolean value after making it into a string, I still get the same boolean value. That's why to understand your problem better I need you to give an example value of your obj to see if there's an issue with it.

Comment: Be aware that some languages and also databases allow nullable booleans/bits, which therefore end up as null. Check the source of the **object** for not being `null`.

Comment: @ Yoel 
-> after converting to string
{"name":"one","value":"true","type":"boolean",""disable":false}  


->after parsing the string value          
{
disable: false
name: "one"
value: null
type: "boolean"
}

Comment: @harsh: It works fine with your provided example. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"name":"one","value":"true","type":"boolean","disable":false}))`. Yet your `value` is passed as a string (see the quotes) and not as a `boolean`.

Comment: @Lain please see my last comment , in that i provided the value which i am getting after converting the object to string and the value i am getting when parsing it. In string the value is "true" but in parsing the value becomes null

Comment: @harsh: You are either putting another object or do more with it than showing here. As you can very easily see with the code I provided above, the issue you described, does not occur (in latest IE11, Edge, Firefox and Chrome).